# Rename xml descendants

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm trying to

1. Load external xml
2. Select only "oldName" nodes
3. Change "oldName" nodes to "newName" nodes
4. Create and save new xml file

The code below does not work, it only creates "items" node.

```
// Load xml
XElement doc = XElement.Load("http://.../file.xml");
var nodes = doc.Descendants().Where(element => element.Name.LocalName.Equals("oldName"));

foreach (var element in nodes)
{
    if (element.Name.LocalName.Equals("oldName"))
    {
        element.Name = "newName";
    }
}

XElement newDoc = new XElement("item", nodes);

// Save xml
newDoc.Save("C:/newFile.xml");
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Selecting "oldName" nodes works, but I need to rename them also.

```
// Load xml
XElement doc = XElement.Load("http://.../file.xml");
var nodes = doc.Descendants().Where(element => element.Name.LocalName.Equals("oldName"));

XElement newDoc = new XElement("item", nodes);

// Save xml
newDoc.Save("C:/newFile.xml");
```

EDIT: Added file example

file.xml

```
<ignoreThisElement>
   <oldName>
      ...
   </oldName>
</ignoreThisElement>
```

newFile.xml

```
<newName>
   ...
</newName>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your code only creates an empty "items" node is because the 'nodes' var no longer contains elements with the old name. You changed all the elements to the new variable, but the linq query still references the old name.

```
// Load xml
XElement doc = XElement.Load("http://.../file.xml");

//using linq to get all nodes with name 'oldName'
var nodes = doc.Descendants().Where(element => element.Name.LocalName.Equals("oldName"));

//you rename the nodes here, so the linq query no longer finds nodes with 'oldName'
foreach (var element in nodes)
{
 if (element.Name.LocalName.Equals("oldName"))
 {
    element.Name = "newName";
 }
}

//result is 'items' node with no children
XElement newDoc = new XElement("item", nodes);

// Save xml
newDoc.Save("C:/newFile.xml");
```

The solution would be for your to extract the required nodes first, then move them to your newDoc element. Thereafter you can rename the nodes:

```
        // Load xml
        XElement doc = XElement.Load("http://.../file.xml");

        var nodes = doc.Descendants().Where(element => element.Name.LocalName.Equals("oldName"));

        //move the extracted old nodes to your newDoc first
        XElement newDoc = new XElement("item", nodes);

         //now rename
        foreach (var element in newDoc.Descendants())
        {
            if (element.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("oldName"))
            {
                element.Name = "newName";
            }
        }

        // Save xml
        newDoc.Save("C:/newFile.xml");
```

Alternatively, you could requery the doc variable for the new node names after renaming them:

```
// Load xml
XElement doc = XElement.Load("http://.../file.xml");

//using linq to get all nodes with name 'oldName'
var nodes = doc.Descendants().Where(element => element.Name.LocalName.Equals("oldName"));

foreach (var element in nodes)
{
  if (element.Name.LocalName.Equals("oldName"))
  {
   element.Name = "newName";
  }
}

//get all newName nodes
var newNodes = doc.Descendants().Where(element => element.Name.LocalName.Equals("newName"));

XElement newDoc = new XElement("item", newNodes);

// Save xml
newDoc.Save("C:/newFile.xml");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution and especially for explanation why is it happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
// Load the xml
var doc = XDocument.Load("http://.../file.xml"); 

// loop thru the element an d search for a specific node and change the name
foreach (var element in doc.Descendants())
{
    if (element.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("oldName"))
    {
        element.Name = "newName";
    }
}

// Save xml
doc.Save("C:/newFile.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XElement doc = XElement.Load(FILENAME);
            List<XElement> nodes = doc.Descendants().Where(element => element.Name.LocalName.Equals("oldName")).ToList();

            for(int index = nodes.Count() - 1; index >= 0; index--)
            {
                XElement node = nodes[index];
                node.ReplaceWith(new XElement("newName", node.Descendants()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```